# Database connection not working over wireless

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a sql server database running.  I can connect to this database when my laptop is plugged in via a wired connection.  I can connect to file shares on the server or remote desktop to the server over wired or wireless.  But I cannot connect to the database over the wireless connection.

Any ideas why this would work over the wired connection only?

Comment: If you create a new ODBC connection (if you're using it) while wireless does the connection through that work (when clicking test connection)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** Never mind.  I had it working this morning, but this afternoon I can't connect again.

---

I got this working.  To fix it, I changed the sql server port rule in the firewall to allow edge traversal:
[image: Allow Edge Traversal]
The reason this works is that our wireless network is on a different vlan (subnet) from our wired network, so from the firewall's perspective the inbound packets were coming through a layer 3 edge device.